# Way to react on deleting any row from table in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

In our database we have many tables (of course). There is one table in our database say files. This table has the list of all the files related to each table like people, contacts etc. Now there is one column (parent record) in  files table that store parent record key (not foreign key in database level because it is not possible that same column has relation to multiple tables) to either people or contacts. Now i want to create something at database level at one place which see we have deleted row from people, so delete all the rows from contacts.

1. One way to create trigger on each table but we have hundreds of tables.
2. We cannot use cascade delete, because relation is not of foreign key.

We cannot change the structure of table as we got existing data.

Thanks

Comment: No relations = :( The only other database-level option (I know of) is .. triggers. If the bulk of the trigger code is the same (e.g. only thing that changes is the tables) it could be automatically generated. Another option is to run a "cleanup job" that will periodically run and perform certain maintenance tasks (e.g. deleting orphaned records).

Answer (score 0):

The approach suggested by 'pst' is essentially a garbage collection approach, and might be favored over the use of triggers.  Not knowing the overall characteristics of the system, if responsiveness is more important, this approach would not add any time to the deletion of a given record.  Put another way, the risk of having unreferenced resources is less than risk of slowing down the delete step.

This sample code will loop through tables with identities and delete any orphans of that table in the centralized 'resource' table.

Assumptions:

- Each of the parent tables has an identity column
- The Resource table 'files' identifies somehow the table to which its parent can be found (this sample has the column 'TableName' hard-coded as an example)

(Posted on Microsft Script Center)
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Garbage-Collection-of-a-99594c13

```
DECLARE @ResourceTableName sysname
SET @ResourceTableName = 'Resource'

--cursor variables
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @primarySchema sysname
DECLARE @primaryTableName sysname
DECLARE @identityColumnName sysname

DECLARE curTableName CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 
AND table_name <> @ResourceTableName

-- loop through tables
OPEN curTableName

FETCH NEXT FROM curTableName
INTO @primarySchema, @primaryTableName, @identityColumnName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = '
        DELETE --SELECT *
        FROM ' + @ResourceTableName + '
        WHERE TableName = ''' + @primaryTableName + '''
        AND ParentID NOT IN (
            SELECT ' + @identityColumnName + ' FROM  ' +  @primarySchema + '.' + @primaryTableName + '
        )'

    --PRINT @sql
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM curTableName
    INTO @primarySchema, @primaryTableName, @identityColumnName
END

-- close a cursor
CLOSE curTableName
DEALLOCATE curTableName
```